# How to unpack all objects of a git repository?

Tags: git, unpack

How can I unpack **all** objects of a pack file?

I've just cloned a remote repository, so my local repository currently doesn't contain any loose object, only a .pack and a .idx files.

I've tried running `git unpack-objects < .git/objects/pack/pack-.pack`, but nothing happens.

I'm doing something wrong? Is there any other command to do that?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to move the pack objects outside the `.git/objects/pack` directory before using the command. However, the pack files need to be inside the repository.

For example, create a directory name `SAMPLE` in your project's root. Then, move the pack files to `SAMPLE` directory. After that, inside the repository without the pack files, use the command

```
git unpack-objects < SAMPLE/*.pack
```

Git will generate all objects inside `.git/objects` directory of your repository.

Comment: Hacky, but valid.  The reason this works is that `git unpack-objects` won't create objects already in the repo, and seeing as the pack file is in the repo it does nothing.  This is very clearly explained in `get help unpack-objects`.

Comment: thanks, just one thing - the pack files do not need to be inside the repo

Comment: I would also add that there's a file `.git/objects/info/packs` which appears to list the pack files available under `.git/objects/packs`. There's also the file `.git/packed-refs` which contains the list of refs (heads, tags) available via pack files. I'm not sure what to do  with them after removing the pack files -- may be they need to be removed, may be `git fsck` would take care of them -- I dunno. Just something to keep in mind just in case...

Comment: When I try the command `git unpack-objects -n < SAMPLE/*.pack`, bash gives me an error: `bash: SAMPLE/*.pack: ambiguous redirect`. Is it because I'm trying to use the `-n` switch? I wanted to try a dry run before committing to the full unpack...

Comment: @WilsonF You have multiple or no pack files (probably multiple). You need to actually run the command once for every .pack file, and specify its actual filename (you can use tab-completion for that though)

Comment: @WilsonF You could also run a simple command like `for file in $(ls SAMPLE/); do git unpack-objects < SAMPLE/$file; done` and achieve your solution.

Comment: This post (`git unpack-objects < SAMPLE/*.pack`) made me do a double-take and think I thought I was mistaken all these years about how Bash handles `<`. **Bash cannot use the `<` operator with multiple files.** You must iterate over them one at a time, e.g. `for fn in SAMPLE/*.pack; do git unpack-objects < "$fn"; done`.

Answer (score 0):

move the *.pack file into .git folder , then go to .git directory and run the following command:

cat YOUR_PACK_FILE.pack | git unpack-objects

Comment: fatal: offset value out of bound for delta base object - from PowerShell

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can try a simple command:

`git clone ***.git`