# Git - obtain sources from .pack archive

Tags: git, repository, pack

I am new to Git, I have cloned a repository with git clone, but I did not obtain any C++ source file (project is written in C++), but instead I have obtained two files in .git/objects/pack, with *.pack and *.idx extension.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972031/how-to-unpack-all-objects-of-a-git-repository) guide to unpack the archives. Now I have in the objects folder 255 folders from 00 to ff which cointain binary files, and I don't know how to obtain the source files needed for working on the project.

Could anyone explain me what these 255 folders are and if there is a way to obtain the source files from them? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The command used to clone the repo is:

```
    git clone git@gins.hostname.com:/path/to/repo
```

Comment: Please include the `git` command that you use to clone the repository in your question.

Comment: Looks like it is not a public repository we can test, so I guess your best shot is to ask the author of that repository what's going on.

Comment: No is not public. I thought it was a common situation to retrieve the contents of a git repository from the object directory.

Comment: It's not, `git` should do it for you automatically.

Comment: What is the output of `git status` and `git log --oneline --decorate`?

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem was that I needed to checkout a specific branch, pull the origin and still than to give the command: "git fetch --all"