# Where can I find snapshot for a specific Git commit?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

I have learned that:

- Git keeps a snapshot for each commit
- A snapshot is essentially `copies` of `changed` files and some `references` to `unchanged` files
- All Git relevant data are stored under `.git` directory inside the repository directory.

```
duong2179-mbpro:.git duong2179$ ls -l
total 480
-rw-r--r--    1 duong2179  admin     742 Oct  2 13:03 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-r--r--    1 duong2179  admin   15646 Oct  2 13:28 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--    1 duong2179  admin      33 Oct  2 13:28 HEAD
-rw-r--r--    1 duong2179  admin      41 Oct  2 13:28 ORIG_HEAD
-rw-r--r--    1 duong2179  admin     849 Oct  2 13:07 config
-rw-r--r--    1 duong2179  admin      73 Apr 24 16:18 description
drwxr-xr-x   17 duong2179  admin     578 Apr 24 16:19 hooks
-rw-r--r--    1 duong2179  admin  185528 Oct  2 13:29 index
drwxr-xr-x    3 duong2179  admin     102 Apr 24 16:18 info
drwxr-xr-x    4 duong2179  admin     136 Apr 24 16:19 lfs
drwxr-xr-x    4 duong2179  admin     136 Apr 24 16:19 logs
drwxr-xr-x  260 duong2179  admin    8840 Aug 19 15:50 objects
-rw-r--r--    1 duong2179  admin   19239 Apr 24 16:19 packed-refs
drwxr-xr-x    5 duong2179  admin     170 Sep 25 16:05 refs
drwxr-xr-x    3 duong2179  admin     102 Aug  5 15:03 subtree-cache
```

Given a Git commit hash where can I find out the associated snapshot in the `.git` sub-directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find it directly if that commit is packed ([delta compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding)): see "[Git Internals - Packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles)"

You would need to verify each pack and see if your commit SHA1 is there:

```
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-978e03944f5c581011e6998cd0e9e30000905586.idx
2431da676938450a4d72e260db3bf7b0f587bbc1 commit 223 155 12
69bcdaff5328278ab1c0812ce0e07fa7d26a96d7 commit 214 152 167
```

You would then need to [unpack that pack file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16972155/6309).

If not packed, see "[Git Internals - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)"

```
$ find .git/objects -type f
.git/objects/01/55eb4229851634a0f03eb265b69f5a2d56f341 # tree 2
.git/objects/1a/410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9 # commit 3
```

The commit 3, for instance, has a SHA1 of `1a410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9`, and has its data in:

```
1a/410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9
```

You can then read the content of that commit metadata with:

```
# Windows:
perl -MCompress::Zlib -e "undef $/; print uncompress(<>)" < 410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9 

# Linux

perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print uncompress(<>)' < 410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9
```

You will get:

```
commit 349 tree 410efbd13591db07496601ebc7a059dd55cfe9 
parent 53316403bc0e36f650796d0afdc0687c52357694
author VonC <VonC@email.com> 1569944592 +0200
committer VonC <VonC@email.com> 1569944592 +0200

This is a commit comment message
```

Comment: Do you mean that snapshots are `somehow` (packed / not packed) stored under the `.git/objects`?

Comment: @duong_dajgja yes, they are.