# What are the demerits of deleting .pack files from a Git repository?

Tags: git

In order to reduce the size of an archived (in the sense that the author doesn't cared much about the history of the repo, but it's preferred if we can retain it) Git repository, if I delete .pack files from it, what will be the issues which I might face in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get the history indeed, since the pack files are [commits packed (delta compressed)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195439/6309), plus their `.idx` index files, [now faster with 2.25](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59255317/6309).

That means a simple [git archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) would be enough to capture the current state of the repo (without history) in a much small file.