# How can I undo the git garbage collector command? I ran git gc

Tags: bash, git, object, github, gitlab

I ran 
`git gc`
to see how git garbage collector works in general.

[image]

But as soon as I ran it,my 15 objects that were shown in .git/objects as blobs, commits, and tree, they are gone. 
1. How to undo it and restore those git objects?
2. When I'll run `ls`, it shows me all the files but what is there status? Where are they at present? They are in the working directory, staging or modified area. And why can't I see them?

Please help me and suggest me If I'm missing some use-case.
[image]

Comment: The objects get packed in the `pack` files, which increases performance. Why would you like to undo the command? It seems to have worked as expected.

Comment: You can use `git unpack-objects` to unpack the pack file again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972031/how-to-unpack-all-objects-of-a-git-repository

Comment: can you please guide how performance increases in this case?

Comment: Packfiles only store the differences between different versions of a file. This reduces the amount of data that needs to be read from disk for most operations. Diffs particularly profit from the delta compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How to undo it and restore those git objects?

I see that this has been answered in the comments, credits to @Sven.

> 2. When I'll run `ls`, it shows me all the files but what is there status? Where are they at present? They are in the working directory, staging or modified area. And why can't I see them?

Well, assuming you are talking about the "linux" `ls` (*i.e.* the one which displays all the files), to see the current status of your git repo, run `git status` which tells you if any file(s) are there in the staging area. This will also tell you which file(s) are not being tracked hence your directory(the things present in your working folder) minus the untracked file(s) gives you your working directory.

Best