# How to unpack a git repository *.pack files using PowerShell?

Tags: git, powershell, command-line

I am aware of this question [How to unpack all objects of a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972031/how-to-unpack-all-objects-of-a-git-repository), but it doesn't help with PowerShell, I googled and even used ChatGPT, but no success yet.

Any help? How to unpack a git repository *.pack files using PowerShell?

Comment: What exactly did you google? The git packfile format is [well documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-format)...

Comment: I am interested in working command for PowerShell to unpack it, it doesn't work using ```git unpack-objects```

Comment: I usually use a ZIP utility like 7-Zip.

Comment: @Dan What kind of error message do you receive with using `git unpack-objects`? If the pack files are corrupted then you'll likely have the same problem with any other tool :)

Comment: Well, as I searched if they are in $GIT_DIR/objects/pack/ ```git unpack-objects``` can't work, so I moved them in ROOT_DIR/pcks/ next to .git folder and it worked in bash using ```git unpack-objects < pcks/*.pack```, but I can't find/write equivalent command for PowerShell.