# fatal: git write-tree failed to write a tree

Tags: git, github, tree

I have a private repository in bitbucket.There are two branch one is **master** and anoter is **eventdesign.** Designer does design in eventdesign branch.Now, i want to merge the eventdesign branch with the master so that i can use the design.i used the following command.

**git fetch origin**

**git merge origin/eventdesign**

But i got the following error

**error: invalid object 100755 6b852b618ad4e91b4c5fe65693731f160b9fb3cb for 'packages/frozennode/administrator/css/ui/images/ui-icons_0073ea_256x240.png'**

**fatal: git write-tree failed to write a tree**

I had searched alot but can't figure it out. Any suggestion will be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: One of the methods described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24868719/6309 could help.

Comment: @VonC when i use git fsck command then i had the output as below:broken link from    tree ddb6e5431c36a26928624338a614dc810a55baf4
              to    blob 2c35e7b60c7eef335a9f47c84b98e3ceaf771d30

Comment: Those methods should be first run in the upstream repo (the one you fetch), on the designer's workstation.

Comment: @VonC sorry ,I did'nt get you..

Comment: You are fetching a repo which might be corrupt. You should first check if the repo managed by the Designer isn't corrupt (before trying to see what is going on in your own local repo)

Comment: @VonC i switched to eventdesign branch and run that command i got the same output as i had written in above comment.

Comment: I don't mean switch branch within your local repo, I mean go and execute those commands in the repo you fetched from

Comment: @VonC how can i do that?

Comment: By contacting your designer and asking him/her to perform similar commands in his/her own local repo.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, designer had run the command and he said that all was fine. So,i delete branch from local and create local branch and track the remote branch which solve my problem :) .Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , i did it . I just delete the branch eventdesign from local

**git branch -d origin/eventdesign**

and then i create the local branch eventdesign and track the remote branch as

**git checkout --track origin/eventdesign**